# Can I change account_name in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a trial snowflake account with url like ie1234.azure.snowflakecomputing.com

I'd like to convert it to paid one for my company and wondering if is possible to change account name to be my company name rather than ie1234?

If I read documentation correctly, account name is generated by snowflake and I cannot configure it unless I'm missing something. Seems strange...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have a paid account rather than a trial account, you can contact your Sales Engineer and request an alias. The URL will still end with the Azure deployment and then snowflakecomputing.com, but you can request a subdomain for your company name if it's still available. The "license plate" name and "vanity plate" name will both work then.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake just released the ability for the Orgadmin Role to rename accounts without Support:

```
ALTER ACCOUNT <account_name> RENAME TO <new_account_name> [ SAVE_OLD_URL = { TRUE | FALSE } ]
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-account.html#syntax